# ¿Como agregar nombre a una aplicacion de Flutter en la multitarea?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, label, multitasking

buenos días.
Tengo una aplicación realizada en Flutter la cual no posee nombre en la multitarea.

Dentro del AndroidManifiest tengo bien agregado el android:label y si entro a las propiedades de la app si tiene nombre.

¿Cuál seria mi error?

Desde ya, muchas gracias.

[image: Nombre de la app]

[image: No posee nombre en la multitarea]

Comment: Coloca tu código de lo que llevas, lo que haz hecho, así podemos ayudarte mejor

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias por responder. Que parte del código seria necesario? El "androidManifest.xml"? En el mismo es donde supuestamente deberia de estar el nombre de la app. Está asi "android:label="Gestion GyA"".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dentro del archivo `main.dart`, tienes que agregar en el `MaterialApp` la propiedad `title`, una vez que lo agregues, deberás recompilar tu aplicación para que puedas apreciar el cambio.

```
   return MaterialApp(
    title: 'Nombre de la app',
    color: Colors.black //o de tu gusto
    );
```

Espero te haya servido.

Comment: Genial! muchas gracias. Esto mismo habia que hacer.